# How to parse XML to columns

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I want to parse this Xml to get the following result. The name of the table is SchoolRecord

```
Name               Answer
School name        87f6c8bf-cafc-40fb-a082-ca9d5bfaf1e0
Course             2f23e1cb-181e-4af2-a9ec-3dd68530d1d5
Father             NULL
Mother             NULL
```

I am using SQL Server 2012. Here's what I have tried but it didn't work

1.

```
Select 
S.userdefinedxml.value('(/ControlGroup/UserDefinedControls/Control/Name)[1]','varchar(max)' ) as Name,
S.userdefinedxml.value('(/ControlGroup/UserDefinedControls/Control/Answer)[1]','varchar(max)' ) as Answer
From SchoolRecord S
```

2.

```
Select 
S.userdefinedxml.value('(School_Data/ControlGroup/UserDefinedControls/Control/Name)[1]','varchar(max)' ) as Name,
S.userdefinedxml.value('(School_Data/ControlGroup/UserDefinedControls/Control/Answer)[1]','varchar(max)' ) as Answer
From SchoolRecord S
```

3.

```
Select 
S.userdefinedxml.value('(Data/School_Data/ControlGroup/UserDefinedControls/Control/Name)[1]','varchar(max)' ) as Name,
S.userdefinedxml.value('(Data/School_Data/ControlGroup/UserDefinedControls/Control/Answer)[1]','varchar(max)' ) as Answer
From SchoolRecord S
```

My Results

```
Name      Answer
NULL      NULL
NULL      NULL
NULL      NULL
NULL      NULL
```

My XML :

```
        <data>
          <School_Data>
            <ControlGroup>
              <UserDefinedControls>
                <Control>
                  <ControlType>FIND</ControlType>
                  <Name>School name</Name>
                  <Answer>87f6c8bf-cafc-40fb-a082-ca9d5bfaf1e0</Answer>
                </Control>
              </UserDefinedControls>
              <UserDefinedControls>
                <Control>
                  <ControlType>FIND</ControlType>
                  <Name>Course</Name>
                  <Answer>2f23e1cb-181e-4af2-a9ec-3dd68530d1d5</Answer>
                </Control>
              </UserDefinedControls>
              <UserDefinedControls>
                <Control>
                  <ControlType>FIND</ControlType>
                  <Name>Father</Name>
                  <Answer />
                </Control>
              </UserDefinedControls>
              <UserDefinedControls>
                <Control>
                  <ControlType>FIND</ControlType>
                  <Name>Mother</Name>
                  <Answer />
                </Control>
              </UserDefinedControls>
            </ControlGroup>
          </School_Data>
        </data>
```

Comment: XML is case-sensitive so try `data` instead of `Data` as you have. e.g. `S.userdefinedxml.value('(data/School_Data/ControlGroup/UserDefinedControls/Control/Name)[1]','varchar(max)' ) as Name,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see Yuck mentioned element and attribute names are case-sensitive.  Below is an example to return the name and answer from each control:

```
SELECT
    Control.value('Name[1]','varchar(max)' ) as Name,
    Control.value('Answer[1]','varchar(max)' ) as Answer
FROM dbo.SchoolRecord S
CROSS APPLY S.userdefinedxml.nodes('/data/School_Data/ControlGroup/UserDefinedControls/Control') AS UserDefinedControls(Control);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out. XML is Case sensitive. I changed Data to data.